# Reading CSV in to an ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I am getting an array out of bounds exception when I run this. I need to read in a CSV to an ArrayList that contains student information in each row. I also need to be able to check if the rows either have missing information or too much information and discard the entire row it does. I feel like I may be doing this completely wrong because I'm not entirely sure how to even do this. 
My main class is

```
public class Main {
    static ArrayList<Student> Students = new ArrayList<Student>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileLocation = getFile();
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    while(!file.exists()) {
        fileLocation = getFile();
    }

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileLocation);
    while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
        String data[] = scnr.nextLine().split(",");
        Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
    }
}

public static String getFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter file location: ");
    String fileLocation = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(fileLocation);
    return fileLocation;
}
}
```

My Student class

```
public class Student {
    public String fName = "";
    public String lName = "";
    public String logonID = "";
    public String randomNumber = "";

public Student (String fName, String lName, String logonID, String randomNumber) {
    this.setName(fName, lName);
    this.setID(logonID);
    this.setNumber(randomNumber);
}

public Student() {
    fName = "";
    lName = "";
    logonID = "";
    randomNumber = "";
}

public void setName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.fName = firstName;
    this.lName = lastName;
}

public void setID(String studentID) {
    this.logonID = studentID;
    logonID.toLowerCase();
}

public void setNumber(String randomNumber) {
    this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
}
}
```

The error i am getting is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)"

andrew,Comma,comma1aj,83559,
Andrew,Karpenter,karpe1aj,966796,15.7
Brandon,Turnip,turni1bw,715855,
Brenda,Miso,miso1b,747747,
Chris,Shoe,shie1c,123784,
David,Cool,Cool1d,200100,
Django,,uncha1d,830700,
Erik,Tata,,400500,
Jakob,Doolittle,dooli1j,555777,
Thomas,Jefferson,jeff1t,951753,
Kaya,Coffee,coffee1k,789456,
Owen,Wilson,wilso1o,456123,
Test,student,seeli1p_s,,
,demo,demo1s,58578,

Comment: Please post the exception and where it points to in the code. Also provide the data you're reading in.

Comment: I "suspect" your error is on `Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));`? Without the data you're actually reading, it's kind of hard to provide you with much more then some guess work. What I would do is a `System.out.println(scnr);` and possibly `System.out.println(data.length);` before it and verify that what you're reading is correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes that is where the error is coming from. I added  a photo of the data. I tried `System.out.println(scnr);` and i got: `java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=23][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=true][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]` which I have no idea what it means.

Comment: `String line = scnr.nextLine(); System.out.println(line);` would give you more information. Please don't post images of data, copy the actual data from the csv file you export from Excel (you can open that with e.g. Notepad).

Comment: @KyleZeien Okay, sorry, it's kind of hard to do this via comments. You should read the line from the `Scanner` into a `String` and print it, then, using that `String` split it and dump the element count. You're looking for the line which triggers the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and make sure it meets your minimum requirements (ie 4 elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with these kind of problems, you should start by putting in some debug statements.

Start by modifying the "reading" aspect of your code to provide more details about what is been read, something like...

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileLocation);
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
    String text = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("text = " + text);
    String[] data = text.split(",")
    System.out.println("data = " + data.length);
    Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
}
```

You need to verify that the text been read in has at least 4 elements.  This will help you identify the line of text which might be give you issues

> Okay I tried this and the text printed the file location that I typed in. The data length was 1 and then I got the exception.

[`Scanner(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) takes the `String` you've supplied as the value to be processed/scanned.  Instead, you want [`Scanner(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-), which will read the file you've specified.

So, instead of `Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileLocation);` try using `Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation));`

> Okay that fixed it and I am now getting the output I want except for the very last "student". I got another array out of bounds exception where the last student should've printed, and I also got an Exception in thread "main" for one of the text outputs for a "student" that has the correct amount of information. When I click on the hyperlinked exception it says source not found for Chris,Shoe,shie1c,123784,Exception. Would checking for the correct amount of data entries fix this?

So based on you sample code, `Test,student,seeli1p_s,,` is generating an array of only 3 elements. Apparently `String#split` drop empty elements by default (ie `,,` produces an empty element, and `split` is dropping it).

To solve this issue, you need to supply `-1` to `String#split`'s `limit` parameter, for example...

```
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
    String text = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);

    String data[] = text.split(",", -1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried this and the text printed the file location that I typed in. The data length was 1 and then I got the exception.

Comment: Okay, use `new Scanner(new File(fleLocation));` instead

Comment: Okay that fixed it and I am now getting the output I want except for the very last "student". I got another array out of bounds exception where the last student should've printed, and I also got an `Exception in thread "main"` for one of the text outputs for a "student" that has the correct amount of information. When I click on the hyperlinked exception it says `source not found for Chris,Shoe,shie1c,123784,Exception`. Would checking for the correct amount of data entries fix this?

Comment: If at all possible post some or all the data in the question, it will make it simpler to debug the code on out end

Comment: Okay I placed it at the end of the post

Comment: So based on you sample code, `Test,student,seeli1p_s,,` is generating an array of only 3 elements (it's dropping the last two `,,` and instead of generating a "empty" element, it's basically ignoring it)

Comment: @KyleZeien Okay, I've updated based on your feed back, it should now be solving both issues. The example will seed missing values with `null` values, so you might still need to validate the data, but at least you will always get at least 4 elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
```

Is the line causing the exception. Instead, you should first check that data contains exactly 4 elements, if not, do not add the student as explained in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should pass the `file` to `Scanner` instead of the `fileLocation`. This would enable the Scanner to read the entire file. Also, update the file after establishing the new location, otherwise the loop may never end. For example:

```
File file = new File(fileLocation); 
while(!file.exists()) { 
  System.out.println("The chosen file doesn't exist, please select another") ;
  fileLocation = getFile(); 
  file = new File(fileLocation); 
}

Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file) ;
```

Now moving to filling the list . You must ensure that all the elements are present before trying to access them. I can think of two options:

**1. Surround the code with a try and catch (not recommended).**

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file); 
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

   String data[] = scnr.nextLine().split(",");
   try{
        Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
   } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace() ;
   } 
}
```

**2. Validate data array**

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file); 
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) { 
   String data[] = scnr.nextLine().split(",");
   if(data.length !=4 || data[0].isEmpty()  ||
   data[1].isEmpty()   ||  data[2].isEmpty()  ||  data[3].isEmpty() ){
    // may add additional checks
   continue; //goes to next iteration
 } 
   Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])); 

}
```